# Show that if the rows of matrix can be split into two orthogonal linear subspaces, then the inverse has each pseudoinverse as columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices, pseudoinverse

Assume an invertible matrix $C$ is in the form $\left[ \begin{matrix}A \\ B \end{matrix}\right]$, where the linear subspace generated by the rows of $A$ is orthogonal to the linear subspace generated by the rows of $B$.  Denote the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverses of $A$ and $B$ by $A^{+}$ and $B^{+}$, respectively.

How would you prove that $C^{-1}=\left[ \begin{matrix}A^{+} & B^{+} \end{matrix}\right]$?

Comment: yes, thank you I fixed it

Comment: Now, did you try multiplying $\left[ \begin{matrix}A \\ B \end{matrix}\right] \left[ \begin{matrix}A^{+} & B^{+} \end{matrix}\right]$ to see if you could $I$?

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, the missing link is that  $A^T B = 0 \implies A^{+} B=0$

Comment: Don't you mean $AB^+ = 0$? Actually, come to think of it, the opposite order$$\left[ \begin{matrix}A^{+} & B^{+} \end{matrix}\right]\left[ \begin{matrix}A \\ B \end{matrix}\right] = A^+A + B^+B$$is probably better. Note that $A^+A$ is the projection matrix onto $\operatorname{colspace} A$, and similarly with $B^+ B$. All you need to do is argue that these columnspaces are orthogonal complements, and that proves their projection matrices sum to $I$.

Comment: @TheoBendit, thank you, that is it indeed!